# Why am I locked out of my machine after uninstalling google authenticator?

Tags: server, ssh, uninstall

I'm completely new to this site, I believe this is the right place to ask for help but I'm not completely sure.

I've had problems with google authenticator on my Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu Server 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" LTS (64bits)) and I decided to uninstall it as it wasn't working to well with Putty and Filezilla altogether.

Note: I followed this guide to uninstall it: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/l/libpam-google-authenticator/uninstall/index.html

But now I'm not able to log in as root or the other user I created strictly not to get locked out of the machine, and I'm wondering if that ever happened to you people?

Thank you

Comment: Did you make changes to configuration files (such as those in `/etc/pam.d/`, or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) when you installed it? If so, uninstalling the package wont have reverted those AFAIK.

Comment: I believe I did, I guess I'm completely locked out now. Shoot.

Comment: Can you still drop to a root shell by booting into recovery mode?

Comment: Oh you are a genius, that I can do